# Service doesn't start when using chef

Tags: linux, chef, service

I've written a script which I trigger as a service. When I call `service myservice start` the service starts fine. However, when the same service is triggered using chef, the service doesnt start.
My chef service code looks like this

```
service "myservice" do
 supports :status => true, :restart => true, :reload => true
 action [ :enable, :start ]
end
```

I call the script using `knife bootstrap <ip> -r 'recipe[testservice]'`.
What am I missing here? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you say what platform you are running this on? And what chef version? The service provider might have something to do with it.

Comment: I use a Centos box. The chef version is 11.4.0.

Comment: In the output from knife bootstrap do you see a line with:  INFO: service[myservice] restarted ?

Comment: I see this `service[myservice] action start
172.16.13.251  (up to date)`

Comment: for some reason chef thinks my service is running when its not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most probably you have some errors in your `/etc/init.d/myservice` script. When you say that yourservice supports `status` command, chef will run `service myservice status` and check the exitcode. If it's 0, it assumes that the service is running. Your script should exit with nonzero code.

Answer (score 0):

When Chef starts a service it first checks if the service is already running ("/sbin/service myservice status" on CentOS). If it determines that it is running already it won't do the start, or log anything at higher than debug level:

https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/service.rb#L87

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, actually the chef 11 server relies on the action :status to start the service. Hence like action start and stop in your script you would also require action status, Which shall return the current status of the script.